# Spark SQL select does not work on DataBricks

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I'm new to Spark SQL and my task is to run a select statement. I have already prepared my data with a temporary table, but it returns invalid syntax error. Please see my code below. Please let me know what I can do to solve it.

```
file_location3 = "/FileStore/tables/flights.csv"

flights = spark.read.format(file_type) \
  .option("inferSchema", infer_schema) \
  .option("header", first_row_is_header) \
  .option("sep", delimiter) \
  .load(file_location3)

display(flights)

flights.createOrReplaceTempView("flights")

%sql
select origin from `flights`

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "<command-840635847173211>", line 55
    select origin from `flights`
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You cannot have both Python and SQL in a single cell. Put the SQL statement in another cell and run it separately. Or use `spark.sql("select ...")` instead.

Comment: +100% to that - you need to execute that in separate cell

Answer (score 0):

You could use spark.sql if you want it to use it in the same cell otherwise you will have to write that in different cell using magic command %sql .